# Electron - My static header files are not being added

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I have a vue.js website with the following dependencies:

```
head: {
    script: [
        {
          src: 'jquery.min.js'
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.splitter@0.27.1/js/jquery.splitter.min.js'
        }
      ],
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.splitter@0.27.1/css/jquery.splitter.css'
      }
    ]
  }
```

It works in the browser, `<script data-n-head="true" src="jquery.min.js"></script>` is succesffully added (for example)

However, with Electron these files are nowhere to be found in the rendered html. I've done some digging on Google but I can't find an answer- does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?